# how send table content to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a problem to send table global from view to controller the table in controller is full but in controller affect a null for the composant of table
and this is the controller method :

```
public Boolean ajoutermodule(string nom, modules[] global, int cv)
{
    return true;
}
```

And this the view and method ajax how i append my table global and how i sent this table global from view to controller :

```
function Addmodule() {
        var nom = $("#nomprojet_I").val();
        var cv = global.length;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Module/ajoutermodule",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                "nom": nom,
                "global": global,
                "cv": cv,
            },
            success: function (responseText) {
                debugger;
                if (responseText == "True") {
                    alert("Succes");
                }
                else {
                    alert("error");
                }
            }
        });

    }

    var global = [];
    function OnGetSelectedFieldValues(s, e) {
        var SelectedUsers = $("#teamlist_I").val() + "    " + $("#teamid_I").val();
        listbox.AddItem(SelectedUsers);


        var nom = $("#teamlist_I").val();

        var id = $("#teamid_I").val();
        global.push({ "id": id, "nom": nom });
        debugger;

    }
```

and when i added the length it send him correctly to controller.

Comment: Don't do things like `var nom = $("#nomprojet_I").val();`, that's how jQuery works and how you should not do Angular. You should keep the values in the model ($scope) and use the DOM strictly as the view and never read back from DOM.

Comment: i use dev express in design and when i want to recover the content of any textbox i use $("#nomprojet_I").val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but method ion your controller like this:
 public Boolean ajoutermodule(string nom, stirng s, int cv)
    {
        return true;
    }

and add this to your method ajax

`var s = JSON.stringify(global);`

```
function Addmodule() {
        var nom = $("#nomprojet_I").val();
var s = JSON.stringify(global);
        var cv = global.length;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Module/ajoutermodule",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                "nom": nom,
                "s": s,
                "cv": cv,
            },
            success: function (responseText) {
                debugger;
                if (responseText == "True") {
                    alert("Succes");
                }
                else {
                    alert("error");
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

it will work inchallah

Comment: thinks you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code for ASP.NET MVC –

**View.cshtml**

```
<table id="StepsTable">
<tr>
    <td>Step 1</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("step1")</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Step 2</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("step2")</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Step 3</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("step3")</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input id="SendToControllerButton" type="button" value="Send to the server"/>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#SendToControllerButton").click(function () {

            var data = {};
            //Collects the data from textboxes and adds it to the dictionary
            $("#StepsTable tr").each(function (index, item) {
                var tds = $(this).find("td");
                var textBoxTitle = $(tds).eq(0).text();
                var textboxValue = $(tds).eq(1).find("input").val();
                data["stepsDictionary[" + index + "].Key"] = textBoxTitle;
                data["stepsDictionary[" + index + "].Value"] = textboxValue;
            });

            //Makes ajax call to controller 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                url: "/Home/ProcessStepsValues",
                success: function (message) {
                    alert(message);
                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

And then sends the data to controller

**Controller.cs**

```
   [HttpPost]
   public string ProcessStepsValues(Dictionary<string, string> stepsDictionary)
       {
           string resultMessage = string.Empty;
           if (stepsDictionary != null)
           {
               resultMessage = "Dictionary data passes to controller successfully!";
           }
           else
           {
               resultMessage = "Something goes wrong, dictionary is NULL!";
           }
           return resultMessage;
       }
```

Please refer the site for more details
https://alexkuznetsov.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/asp-net-mvc-pass-dictionary-data-from-view-to-controller/

Comment: the problem that the in methode ajax the content of table are correct  but when i send this content to method controller it sent him null      i think that problem serialisation